# What is the difference between PostProcessorInterface and postProcessAlgorithm in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

[`QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface.postProcessLayer()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface.html?highlight=postprocessorinterface#module-QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface)

vs

[`QgsProcessingAlgorithm.postProcessAlgorithm()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsProcessingAlgorithm.html?highlight=postprocessalgorithm#qgis.core.QgsProcessingAlgorithm.postProcessAlgorithm)

They both seem to post-process a layer like style it or change its display name. What are the differences and which is the recommended method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after reading through multiple docs and answers. This is my understanding:

`QgsProcessingAlgorithm.postProcessAlgorithm()`
You can do anything here related to canvas or not, literally almost anything. This runs first after the `processAlgorithm` in `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`. This is the part of `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class.

`QgsProcessingLayerPostProcessorInterface.postProcessLayer()`
On the other hand this is not part of the `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` class and is run after `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` is completely finished. It does not do anything apart from attaching its `postProcessLayer` function to the layer on which it was added. (the function is not executed here)

When QGIS natively outputs layers after the algorithm is finished, it will apply the `postProcessLayer` function as the last step.